# Selecting documents with the Firebase CLI

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-tools

When using the firebase CLI with a Realtime Database
I can use a command like this one to read a collection:

```
 % firebase database:get DB_Path
```

But I can't find a way to select only the documents I need.

I have a hard time to believe that it could be impossible.

Something like:

```
 % firebase database:get DB_Path where (name='Biden Joe')
```

Is there a proper syntax to do that ?

Comment: Have you run the command `firebase database:get --help` to see your options?

Comment: Indeed this gives some hints, but nothing working. I tried a few things like:
firebase database:get DB_Path  --order-by-key name --equal-to {"name":"Biden Joe"}.
But it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To learn the options for the `database:get` command, run `firebase database:get --help` as in:

```
% firebase database:get --help
Usage: firebase database:get [options] <path>

fetch and print JSON data at the specified path

Options:
  -o, --output <filename>  save output to the specified file
  --pretty                 pretty print response
  --shallow                return shallow response
  --export                 include priorities in the output response
  --order-by <key>         select a child key by which to order results
  --order-by-key           order by key name
  --order-by-value         order by primitive value
  --limit-to-first <num>   limit to the first <num> results
  --limit-to-last <num>    limit to the last <num> results
  --start-at <val>         start results at <val> (based on specified ordering)
  --end-at <val>           end results at <val> (based on specified ordering)
  --equal-to <val>         restrict results to <val> (based on specified ordering)
  --instance <instance>    use the database <instance>.firebaseio.com (if omitted, use default database instance)
  -h, --help               output usage information
```

So you can get all child nodes of your name with:

```
firebase database:get /users --order-by "name" --equal-to "Michael"
```

Don't forget to [define an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) for "name" in your rules.